# Multiple window bind same data with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, http, rest, angularjs

I tried something and didn't find the best way to do it yet.
I have my main angular app that bind data and want to find a way to open pop-ups (not modal but true window) that bind same data.

I found how to share a service with SharedService between controllers of one app but when I create new window, it's not the same instance of the app and so, didn't work.

Is it possible to import a service from an app to an other by http ? Or do you know an other method to make mutliple windows that bind same data in real time.

Thanks by advance,

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as the widest scope your angular app can control is bound to the html element, which is different on each page.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. Do you think it can be possible if I work with RESTful resources and update their properties (in a persistant way) each time user do an action on data ?

Comment: You might want to check out Firebase for AJ. It provides real time data sync.

Comment: Didn't try yet, but just find a sample and it seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments.
I found a solution to do what I want.
I used http post to get data from REST services. All my windows (or pages) bind data from the same REST services. And I send the params needed in http request by urls.